# Angular 5 Keycloak : Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error

Tags: angular

```
@Injectable()
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  tpps = TPPArray;
  selected = ''
  token: Observable<any>;
  selectedTPP: TPP;

onSelect(tpp: TPP): void {
  this.selectedTPP = tpp;
}

readonly ROOT_URL = 'localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token';
posts : any;    

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getToken() {
const data: Post = {
username: 'pierrecolart',
password: 'root',
grant_type: 'password',
client_id: 'admin-cli'
}
this.http
    .post(
        this.ROOT_URL,
        data, 
        {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')}
    )
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => console.log(data))
}
}
```

When I try to post to keycloak I have this error and I do not understand why?

Keycloak is running on localhost I have verified it

SO I do not have a problem with that

Comment: Have you tried to implement some [error handling](https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling)?

Comment: @Jeto that can change something ?

Comment: Well that can give you clues at least?

Comment: Silly question but I have to ask. Did you try to add `http://` to your url ?

Comment: @mickdev you are the best :D